# How to set Spring HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory with Apache httpcomponent5?

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to set httpClient5 in Spring ... I have the following code:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                        .setSslContext(SSLContexts.createSystemDefault())
                        .setTlsVersions(TLS.V_1_3, TLS.V_1_2)
                        .build())
                .setDefaultSocketConfig(SocketConfig.custom()
                        .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
                        .build())
                .setPoolConcurrencyPolicy(PoolConcurrencyPolicy.STRICT)
                .setConnPoolPolicy(PoolReusePolicy.LIFO)
                .setConnectionTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMinutes(1L))
                .build();

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
                        .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
                        .setCookieSpec(StandardCookieSpec.STRICT)
                        .build())
                .build();

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

        HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        clientContext.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        clientContext.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        clientContext.setRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5000))
                .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5000))
                .build());



        // connect Spring httpComponent (client-side) with Apache httpClient
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(60000);
        httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        httpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
```

the class ClosableHttpClient implements the interface org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient that is not compatible with setHttpClient(client); this the runtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient (org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient and org.apache.http.client.HttpClient are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I'm using Spring 5.0 and HttpComponents-client-5. How to convert HttpClient 4.X to HttpClient 5 ?

Answer (score 11):

Apache HttpClient 4.5 and HttpClient 5.0 classic are very similar but are fully API *incompatible*.

Until Spring provides Apache HttpClient 5.x based `RequestFactory` implementation one cannot integrate HttpClient 5.x with Spring.

Comment: I have just attempted to do this and I believe as of June 2021, this is still the case.

Comment: Hello guys, we're having the same problem here. Do you know if any progress were made in the last 12 months? Cheers

Comment: Up to now, it still cannot be integrated. Mainly because of the lhttpcomponentsclienthttprequestfactory

Comment: Nov 9th 2022 ..still no compatible..

Comment: this is now possible with a small change using the connection manager:
https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl

Answer (score 3):

> NOTE: Requires Apache HttpComponents 5.1 or higher, as of Spring 6.0.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html

Comment: yay, makes supporting libraries across both spring 5 / 6 completely impossible. yippee. :|

Answer (score 2):

```
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStore), keyStorePassword.toCharArray(), keyPassword.toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStore), trustStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new BatchException(ex, "Unable to create SSL context");
        }
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setResponseTimeout(TIME_OUT,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIME_OUT,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .setConnectionManager(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                                .setSslContext(sslContext)
                                .setHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .build();
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

    }
```

Comment: I have done the changes by this way. and it is working fine.

Comment: dependency was httpclient5